# Need to Redirect any possible typed in url to new domain on same server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains on the same server pulling from the same wordpress database, I would like anytime someone types in sitea.com/random to be redirected to siteb.com/random.  I am able to redirect the homepage with

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2\.sitea\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.www2\.sitea\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www2\.siteb\.com" [R=301,L]`

However this does not forward any URL with a trailing URL (ex. sitea.com/random/).  I have used the wildcard option to forward everything to the new domain, however since the sites are pulling from the same IP, it runs into a redirect loop.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it was not that easy, but I did end up finding an answer.  In wp-config.php I added and ran the function

```
    function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
$redirect = str_replace("www2.", "", curPageURL());
$remove_http_root    = str_replace('http://', '', $redirect);
$split_url_array     = explode('/', $remove_http_root );


if($split_url_array[0] == "olddomain.com"){
    header("Location: http://www2.newdomain.com/$split_url_array[1]");
    die();
}
```

and then I added a simple redirect for the homepage in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2\.olddomain\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.www2\.olddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www2\.newdomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Hopefully this will help someone else. And maybe someone will come up with a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2\.sitea\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.www2\.sitea\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www2.siteb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it was a bit more complicated than this

Comment: Yes, it did not redirect correctly for me.  I think it is because they are hosted on the same IP and I am getting an infinite loop